# How to find who have completed development of defects on JIRA development tracking tool?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, issue-tracking, jql, jira-agile

Our Team is Using Development tracking tools Jira for the development cycle. We extract issue details in Excel sheet and do a further activity.

Can we get data in a column of the people, who have completed development from a workflow or in other words who have Fixed issues?.

Right now, we have to open all the issue and watch manually,  who have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQL:

> status was "Resolved" by username

If you want to see all the issues resolved by a particular user. If you have a small team you could create a filter for each user in the team that would return the bugs they resolved.

You can also do it for a list of users:

> status was "Resolved" by (username1, username2, username3)

I don't believe you can export the "resolved by" field though. An alternative would be to create a custom field called RESOLVED_BY and have the team members complete this when they resolve an issue. An even more sophisticated approach would be to automatically populate the RESOLVED_BY field when the issue is resolved.

It is also worth noting that most of the time the ASSIGNEE for a resolved issue will most likely be the person that resolved the issue.